# Strange effect in fabric when running sudo ps -ef

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

My system is setup to allow for a certain user to run sudo commands without password prompting. This has been working fine for ages. Now I come across a very unusual problem, where certain commands are prompting for a sudo password. I think this is because fabric is parsing the output and decides that a password is being requested on the far end.

But, actually, this is wrong! No password is being requested (I can run the same command just fine with ssh, no passwords prompted). I have at least identified the command `ps -ef` as problematic, I think because of the kind of output that is being produced.

In fact, the command `ps -ef` is also showing the command that fabric is using to run this command on the far end, and I think this is confusing fabric. It is probably thinking that a  `sudo` in the output means password is needed. This is the part of the output which is blocking fabric to prompt for a password:

```
[aaaa@bbbb:22] out: aaaa      9917  9790  0 15:10 ?        00:00:00 sshd: aaaa@notty 
[aaaa@bbbb:22] out: root      9918  9917  0 15:10 ?        00:00:00 sudo -S -p sudo password:
```

Is it possible to tell fabric no to parse the output at all, or at least not to prompt for a password?

Answer (score 0):

try setting your shell to false before calling your command.

```
env.shell = False
```